# UIImagePicker force photo in portrait mode (disable accelerometer)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

I'm building an application which takes photos using the UIImagePickerController. Works great.

The problem however is that I don't want to use image rotation. I always want a photo in portrait mode just as the user sees it on the screen.

When you take your iPhone on the side and then slowly take it back to normal the orientationmode isn't updated. Now when you take the photo the orientation flags in the EXIF data are set.

Is there a way to get rid of orientation support in de imagepicker? Could I just disable the accelerometer?